# PHP rule for views exposed filter

Tags: 7, panels, views

I'm writing a visibility rule for an element on a Panel page that also has a view with exposed filter. The goal is to show this element only when the filter isn't set. Is there a way to check weather the view on the current page was filtered with exposed filter or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be other more convenient solutions but this is a quick one, in some cases it wont work or suit at all (it will work on pages with clean urls), but you can perform current path validation by this code:

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();
$destination = $destination['destination'];

// validate if path contains "?" from exposed filter

if (preg_match("/\?/", $destination)) {
return FALSE;
}
else {
return TRUE;
}
```